# javascript wait til function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a javascript function that goes like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
            moveUp();
            break;
        case 40:
            moveDown();
            break;
    }
});
function moveDown() {
    $('element').animate({top: "100%"}, {duration: 1000 });
}
function moveUp() {
    $('element').animate({top: "-100%"}, {duration: 1000 });
}
```

My question is how would I create a delay in the `keydown` function that tells it that it has to wait until the function `moveUp()/movedown()` is finished before calling the function again without creating a queue?

Thank you for all the advise, by the way, I cant use `setTimeout` because it would cause a delay on every initial function.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/ perhaps?

Comment: Do a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for 1sec/timeout second?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user presses up/down while an animation is in progress? Should their keypress have an effect after the animation is done? Or should it be ignored?

Comment: Or just use the `.stop()` function

Comment: I would have used a `flag` if any animation is under process and in `complete` callback, would have reset it.. In other event, Using `setInterval` to test the state of the flag if flag is `true`

Comment: maybe not the best way, but you can set a flag, and change it in your [complete] of animate().. so you check the flag when key is pressed

Comment: Use `jQuery.animate` function callback `complete` to acheive this. On first click unbind the keydown event, on complete bind the keydown event again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you, I used the complete function of the animate to execute the next action as soon as it's finish animating.

```
var isAnimating = false;
var callAfterFinish = undifined;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38:
            moveUp();
            break;
        case 40:
            moveDown();
            break;
    }
});
function moveDown() {
    if(!isAnimating){
        $('element').animate({top: "100%"}, {duration: 1000 },function(){
            if(!callAfterFinish) {
                callAfterFinish();
                callAfterFinish = undifined;
            }
            isAnimating = false;
        });
        isAnimating = true;
    } else if(!callAfterFinish) {
        callAfterFinish = moveDown;
    }
}
function moveUp() {
    if(!isAnimating){
        $('element').animate({top: "-100%"}, {duration: 1000 },function(){
            if(!callAfterFinish) {
                callAfterFinish();
                callAfterFinish = undifined;
            }
            isAnimating = false;
        });
        isAnimating = true;
    } else if(!callAfterFinish) {
        callAfterFinish = moveUp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want keypresses to have no effect at all while an animation is in progress, this should help. When the animation is about to start, I set a variable called `inProgress` to `true`. I set it back to `false` in the completed handler for the animation. In the keydown handler, I check that flag, and if an animation is in progress, I ignore the key.

```js
var position = 50;
var inProgress = false;

function move() {
  inProgress = true;
  $('#box').animate({ top: position + 'px', duration: 1000 }, function () {
    inProgress = false;
  });
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (inProgress) {
    return;
  }
  switch(e.which) {
    case 38:
      e.preventDefault();
      position -= 10;
      move();
      break;
    case 40:
      e.preventDefault();
      position += 10;
      move();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="position:absolute;top:50px;background-color:blue;width:50px;height:50px"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's easy solution.

```js
var flag = true;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if(flag == true){
   switch (e.which) {
      case 38:
        moveUp();
        break;
      case 40:
        moveDown();
        break;
    }
  }
  
});



function moveDown() {
  $('#elem').animate({
    top: "100px"
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    start: function(){ flag=false; },
    complete: function(){flag=true; }
  });
}

function moveUp() {
 
  $('#elem').animate({
    top: "0px"
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    start: function(){ flag=false; },
    complete: function(){flag=true; }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background: green; width: 100px; height: 100px; position:absolute;" id="elem">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may suggest you to set a data attribute.

The [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a complete callback. So before starting the animation you may set the attribute to false and when the animation is completed you may reset to true this attribute.

This attribute can be tested in the keydown event to decide if it's right to continue.

```js
$(function () {
  // set the data attribute to true
  $(document).data('isAnimateCompleted', true);

  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // if false return
    if ($(document).data('isAnimateCompleted') == false) {
      return;
    }
    switch(e.which) {
      case 38:
        moveUp();
        break;
      case 40:
        moveDown();
        break;
    }
  });
  function moveDown() {
    // before starting set to false
    $(document).data('isAnimateCompleted', false);
    $('#element').animate({top: "100px"}, 1000, function() {
      // when completed set to true
      $(document).data('isAnimateCompleted', true);
    });
  }
  
  function moveUp() {
    $(document).data('isAnimateCompleted', false);
    $('#element').animate({top: "0px"}, 1000, function() {
      $(document).data('isAnimateCompleted', true);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="element" style="position: fixed;top: auto;">This is an element</div>
```

Another possibility is to use the jQuery [animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector to test if the animation is in progress avoiding at all global variables.